# How do I setValue (result from a function) in a for loop (GAS)?

Tags: function, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looping over a range, whose 7th column is supposed to get the result of a function.

This is the piece where I loop over the range:

```
var newEntryRng = destSheet.getRange(7,1,destSheet.getLastRow(),9).getValues()
  for (var r = 0; r < newEntryRng.length; r++) {
      var latestCategory = newEntryRng[r][6]; 
      latestCategory.setValue(mostRecentCat());
    }
```

Here's the function mostRecentCat:

```
function mostRecentCat() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('New Entry');
    var dbSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
    var dbRng = dbSheet.getRange(2, 1, dbSheet.getLastRow(), 9).getValues();
    var newEntryRng = destSheet.getRange(7, 1, destSheet.getLastRow(), 9).getValues();
    var latestEntry = [];

    dbRng.sort(function (a, b) {
      var A = new Date(a[1]).valueOf();
      var B = new Date(b[1]).valueOf();
      return B - A;
    });
    for (var j = 0; j < newEntryRng.length; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dbRng.length; i++) {
        if (newEntryRng[j][0] != '' && dbRng[i][0] != '' && 
        newEntryRng[j][5] == dbRng[i][5] && 
        newEntryRng[j][7] == dbRng[i][7] && 
        newEntryRng[j][8] == dbRng[i][8]) {
          latestEntry.push(dbRng[i][6]);
          break;
        }
        
      }
    }
    return latestEntry;
  }
```

This is giving me

> TypeError: latestCategory.setValue is not a function

The struggle is getting this to give me the result for each row iterated.

Comment: latestCategory is undefined in your example so we can't help you.  You might wish to take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Hi, @Cooper! It's declared within the for loop. I actually, can't find a way of setting the result in the 7th column of the range iterated over.

Comment: sorry I meant mostRecentCat() is undefined

Comment: setValue() is a Range method and latestCategory is a value or a string but certainly not a range.  getValues() returns a 2d array of values or strings

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet, redact confidential data as needed. We would need to look at what's going on